# Is it possible to calculate the difference between 2 Time Fields with Formula?

Tags: formula, time

I am trying to calculate the difference between 2 **Time**-fields with a **FORMULA** . (So no DateTime)

I know it is possible in Apex, but I am wondering if it is possible in a Formula as well. I tried a lot already, but it gives an error when I try to open the record. I added the formula field to the TimeSlot-object.

Thanks!

UPDATE: So apparently this is not possible on the TimeSlot-object, because I tried it on another object(custom object, with 2 custom time fields) and that works. Does anyone have an idea?